# Highcharts not rendered properly on production server

Tags: javascript, highcharts, sankey-diagram

I don't know why, but my sankey diagram can't be rendered properly on my [production server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtzVk.jpg) (shared hosting), yet it works perfectly on my [localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sueAu.jpg).

Here's a [pen](https://codepen.io/puntodamar/pen/KBvmZe) with the same data. As you can see, there's nothing wrong there. 
Is it because of how I passed data into javascript?

```js
<script>
    var transferData = '<?php echo json_encode($transfer_data); ?>';
    transferData = JSON.parse(transferData);

    var nodes = '<?php echo json_encode($nodes); ?>';
    nodes = JSON.parse(nodes);
    var subtitle = '<?php echo json_encode($subtitle); ?>';
    subtitle = JSON.parse(subtitle);
</script>
```

Comment: Any error on the production server's error log or in the console ?

Comment: nah... nothing.

Comment: Are you sure that the data of the chart on your server is the same like on the local? Please make sure about it, and let me know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i solved it myself.
the format for sankey diagram is [from, to, value]. 
With the same code, the values are integers on my localhost, yet on my server are strings. So i just cast those values to integer.

How is that possible?